# Computing Nullspace from USV

Tags: r, svd

I am trying to compute the right NullSpace, K,  of the Matrix S using the  R language, but the coded program returned only NULL, what can i do?

```
r1<-c(1,0,0,0)
r2<-c(-1,1,0,0)
r3<-c(0,-1,1,0)
r4<-c(0,-1,0,1)
r5<-c(0,0,-1,0)
r6<-c(0,0,0,-1)
S<-cbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
m<-ncol(S)
n<-nrow(S)


K<-null(t(S))= Null

# [IN Octave] K=null(S');
 K = 
   0.308572   0.487972
   0.308572   0.487972
   0.576882  -0.023245
  -0.268311   0.511217
   0.576882  -0.023245
  -0.268311   0.51121
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) Null** Note that MASS comes with R so you don't have to install it.  Internally `Null` uses the QR decomposition.

```
library(MASS)
Null(t(S))
```

giving:

```
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.4218763  0.3941493
[2,]  0.4218763  0.3941493
[3,]  0.5522815 -0.1682810
[4,] -0.1304052  0.5624303
[5,]  0.5522815 -0.1682810
[6,] -0.1304052  0.5624303
```

**2) svd** If by USV in the subject you mean you want to get it from the singular value decomposition then:

```
SVD <- svd(crossprod(S))
Rank <- sum(zapsmall(SVD$d) > 0)
SVD$v[, -seq_len(Rank)]
```

giving:

```
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  0.2077046 -0.53869484
[2,]  0.2077046 -0.53869484
[3,]  0.5703757 -0.08946994
[4,] -0.3626711 -0.44922489
[5,]  0.5703757 -0.08946994
[6,] -0.3626711 -0.44922489
```

**3) eigen** or from the eigenvalue decomposition of S'S then:

```
e <- eigen(crossprod(S))
Rank <- sum(zapsmall(e$values) > 0)
e$vectors[, -seq_len(Rank)]
```

giving:

```
     [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.0 0.5773503
[2,]  0.0 0.5773503
[3,] -0.5 0.2886751
[4,]  0.5 0.2886751
[5,] -0.5 0.2886751
[6,]  0.5 0.2886751
```

For any of these premultiply by `S` to verify that `S` does, in fact, take any of them to the nullspace.

Comment: Thank you so much  @G. Grothendieck